# How to store which user accessed which page in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have these 3 pages `Index`, `About` and `Contact`. I want to store into the database which user accessed which page. How do I do this?

Controller:

```
namespace Sample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserActivityLogEntities _db = new UserActivityLogEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About(UserActivityLog model)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public partial class UserActivityLog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is effectively the mvc web app scaffold + an extremely minimal amount of code. Add a dbset, generate a migration to create a table to store this data, save the data

Comment: This is too broad for a single question here.  You'll need to put in some initial effort for things like getting information about the user, writing information to a database, etc.  All of which have tutorials and examples available online.  Make some attempt.  If you get stuck somewhere, we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If a user is logged into your site they will have a session cookie.

You can get the session cookie using something like this:

```
var sessionID = Response.Cookies[".ASPXFORMSAUTH"].Value;
```

You can use this on each of your controller methods to figure out if the same user is visiting multiple pages of your site.